# Phone slowdown after Jelly bean update

Tags: 4.1-jelly-bean

I have Sony Xperia P phone which is updated to Jelly bean when they rolled out the update. It came with Gingerbread and I updated it to ICS, as soon as I got it. It was running great.

But it's started to give me problems since I updated it to Jelly-bean. Even the recent minor release didn't fix the slow down issue.
To give the example of slow down, I am getting Slow FPS and sometimes frozen screen for half a second whenever I play a game. Slow FPS is universal for all the apps. When I had ICS I could play games like Subway surfer without any problem, and now I can't play it due to low FPS. Sometimes the System UI gets killed, whenever I start any normal game (such as Samurai v/s Zombie defence).
I don't know if it's a universal problem or just my bad luck, but one of my friend who bought the phone with me, is facing the same issue too. Any idea how can I make my phone run fast again?

Comment: JB was supposed to be faster than ICS :-(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some [bugs reported](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=54978) in the Xperia P Jelly Bean update `6.2.A.0.400`. Even if it is [suggested to perform a factory reset](http://talk.sonymobile.com/message/461637#461637), the problem has not seemed to have fully solved.

So your problem will not most probably be fixed until Sony releases a new version with bug fixes *(and it might take some time)*

<sup>*Note: Since you are mainly concerned with your gaming apps, you might need to check the incompatibilities from the Google Play Store.*</sup>

Comment: They have already released one update - 6.2.A.1.100, which also didn't solve the issues. I used to play those games and run those apps fluidly in ICS. It's not just about playing the games, I bought this phone to test the apps I develop, and now it's useless for this.

Comment: Thanks anyways, atleast now I know, I am not alone here, so can expect an update from sony.

Comment: @Creator Hang on to Sony *(like me)*. They're slow sometimes. Still they are full of surprises! :)